# Populating checkboxes from ArrayList of Objects in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, checkbox, struts2, ognl

I'm sure that I'm doing something dumb but I've been having difficulty over the last couple of days trying to get my *checkboxes* filled out inside an iterator that goes over an `ArrayList` of `Object`.

Here is my object:

```
public class EmailObject {
int emailId;
String emailAddress;

public int getEmailId() {
    return emailId;
}
public void setEmailId(int emailId) {
    this.emailId = emailId;
}
public String getEmailAddress() {
    return emailAddress;
}
public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
    this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
}
}
```

In my action class, I create an `ArrayList` of the above `EmailObject`s.

On my JSP page, I can get checkboxes through a `checkboxlist` (but this isn't good for me because I want it to be vertical and don't want to mess with the Struts styles)

```
<s:checkboxlist name="selectedEmails" list="userEmails" listValue="emailAddress" listKey="emailId" />
```

I can also iterate over the `ArrayList userEmails` and display the values:

```
<s:iterator value="userEmails" var="thisEmailData">
<s:property value="emailId"/>
<s:property value="emailAddress"/>
</s:iterator>
```

But I can't get it to display the `emailId` when iterating over the `ArrayList userEmails`.  I tried all of these:

```
    <s:iterator value="userEmails" var="thisEmailData">
<tr><td><s:property value="emailId"/></td></tr>

<tr><td>
    <s:checkbox fieldValue="%{#emailId}" name="emailAddressesCB"   theme="simple"  ></s:checkbox>
    <s:checkbox fieldValue="#emailId" name="emailAddressesCB"   theme="simple" ></s:checkbox>
    <s:checkbox fieldValue="thisEmailData.emailId" name="emailAddressesCB"   theme="simple" ></s:checkbox>
    <s:checkbox fieldValue="userEmails.emailId" name="emailAddressesCB"   theme="simple" ></s:checkbox>
    <s:checkbox fieldValue="#thisEmailData.emailId" name="emailAddressesCB"   theme="simple" ></s:checkbox>
    <s:checkbox fieldValue="#userEmails.emailId" name="emailAddressesCB"   theme="simple" ></s:checkbox>
    <s:checkbox fieldValue="%{#thisEmailData.emailId}" name="emailAddressesCB"   theme="simple" ></s:checkbox>
    <s:checkbox fieldValue="%{#userEmails.emailId}" name="emailAddressesCB"   theme="simple" ></s:checkbox>
    <s:checkbox fieldValue="emailId" name="emailAddressesCB"   theme="simple"  ></s:checkbox>
    
    <s:checkbox value="%{#emailId}" name="emailAddressesCB"   theme="simple"  ></s:checkbox>
    <s:checkbox value="#emailId" name="emailAddressesCB"   theme="simple" ></s:checkbox>
    <s:checkbox value="thisEmailData.emailId" name="emailAddressesCB"   theme="simple" ></s:checkbox>
    <s:checkbox value="userEmails.emailId" name="emailAddressesCB"   theme="simple" ></s:checkbox>
    <s:checkbox value="#thisEmailData.emailId" name="emailAddressesCB"   theme="simple" ></s:checkbox>
    <s:checkbox value="#userEmails.emailId" name="emailAddressesCB"   theme="simple" ></s:checkbox>
    <s:checkbox value="%{#thisEmailData.emailId}" name="emailAddressesCB"   theme="simple" ></s:checkbox>
    <s:checkbox value="%{#userEmails.emailId}" name="emailAddressesCB"   theme="simple" ></s:checkbox>
    <s:checkbox value="emailId" name="emailAddressesCB"   theme="simple"  >
     </s:checkbox>
     <s:property value="emailAddress"/>
</td></tr>
</s:iterator>
</td></tr>
</s:iterator>
```

From the above, the value field is never filled with the value of the `emailId`.

I know I'm missing something basic.  What is it?

Comment: Can you post your Action class?

Answer (score 1):

You can do following.

```
<s:iterator value="EmailObjects">       
<s:checkbox name="emailAddressess"  fieldValue="%{emailAddress}" 
label="%{emailId}" >
</s:checkbox>
</s:iterator>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using hashmaps instead in the action class. Example

```
Hashmap<int,String> emailobjMap = new Hashmap<int,String>()
    emailobjMap.put(emailId,emailAddress);
    request.setAttribute(EMAILIST, emailobjMap);
```

And in your jsp file using jstl tag library-

```
<g:forEach var="list" items="${EMAILIST}">`

    <g:out value="${list.key}" />
    <g:out value="${list.value}" />
</g>
```

Comment: Thanks crazy, but it seems like a rather roundabout way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a simple meaning that corresponds to checkboxes. The checkboxes has only two states checked or unchecked. If checkbox is checked then `checked="checked"` is added to the `input` tag, when unchecked is removed. How do you think which data type variable is appropriate to represent these states? I think you got it, it's a boolean type. Now lets look at the [example](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/checkbox-tag.html#examples) of checkbox tag on the struts site. They say `value="aBoolean"`. Unfortunately this required more description like

```
Boolean aBoolean;
```

This variable is evaluated via OGNL and if it has `true` value then `checked="checked"` is added and you can see the check sign, otherwise removed.

Comment: So are you saying that struts doesn't support adding values for checkboxes like in standard html? For example: `code`<input type="checkbox" name="color" value="red">Red<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="color" value="blue">Blue<br>`code`   Using the checkboxlist certainly gives unique emailIds in the value field of the checkbox (like normal html does)

Comment: Checked is a standard parameter with either a true or false value, but I believe it is only used for prepopulating the checkbox.  On submit, the multiple values of the checked checkboxes are returned either in a post or on the query string.

Comment: Multiple values are returned if you have multiple checkboxes with the same `name` and it concern any form `input` element. The `value` in HTML corresponds `fieldValue` in struts. About `checked` I already have written above.

Comment: Thank you Roman, I agree, checkboxes have been working like that since my old Perl days.  My question is how to get the fieldvalue set in the checkbox through the iterator. It is displayed OK outside of the checkbox when using property as just emailId, but when putting it into the fieldvalue checkbox parameter it does not work.  It also works find as emailId when within the checkboxLIST tag, so the values are definitely being passed onto the page.

Comment: You can get it if you submit the form in the field that correspond to `name` attribute. Because after struts render HTML fieldvalue becomes value. If you want to get it back in the struts value attribute put a boolean than indicates the state for the value in the fieldvalue. say if you have "red", "green", "blue" values which ones should be checked?